# Will the rules of calculus stay the same when a real-valued function is defined over infinite number of variables?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

So the question would be:

1. Can we ever talk about a real-valued function that is defined over infinite number of variables?
2. Will the rules of calculus remain the same for such functions described in 1.?

Comment: about which rules are you talking ?

Comment: It is possible (e.g. functions defined on spaces [$l_p$ or $L_p$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)), but it is significantly different, e.g. neither the [Heine–Borel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) nor the [Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) are true for infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Differentiation/integration rules for the functions that we know how to differentiate/integrate and the fact that when partial derivative  of function respect to each variable is zero for every variablel, function is a constant function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a theory of "calculus on Banach spaces", which comes close to what you are asking for. See for example [Wikipedia:Fréchet derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) for some information about Fréchet and Gateaux derivatives for functions $f : U \to V$ where $U$ and $V$ are [Banach spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space).

Some things remain the same in the infinite dimensional setting, but some things are fundamentally different. For example the closed unit ball in a Banach space is compact if and only if the space is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1, of course we can. Consider $X:= \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} = \{f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb N\}$, the set of all sequences of real numbers. It's perfectly reasonable to want to talk about functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. Or if you don't want to have to deal with the fact that a function $f: X \to \mathbb R$ depends on "infinitely many variables", you can specialise to $c_c = \{(x_n)_{n\geq1} \in X \mid x_n$ is eventually $0\}$.

*Unfortunately* $X$ (and $c_c$ for that matter) is not all that well-behaved. While it does have a natural [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) which is even [metrisable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrisable_space), it's missing many of the nice properties that makes the set of real numbers so useful—for example it's not [locally compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) and it admits linear maps into the reals that are not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to Lebesgue Measure, which is used to define volume and hence integration on $\mathbb R ^n$ for $n \lt \infty$, for infinite dimensional spaces. Formally this means that there is no measure on any infinite-dimensional Banach $B$ space which is:

1) Locally finite: Each point hasan open neighborhood with finite measure.

2) Strictly positive: Every nontrivial open subset has strictly positive measure.

3) Translation Invariance: If $E \subseteq B$ and $\mu(E) = L$ then $\mu(E+x) = L  \ \forall x \in B$.

This is proved by showing that we can exploit the infinite-dimensionality of the unit ball to pack infinitely many balls of radius $\frac{1}{4}$ inside it. Which leads to the conclusion that the unit ball has infinite measure.

So there is no directly analogous way to define definite integration for functions with infinite-dimensional domain.

Comment: I am just looking at Frechet derivatives, but what about it? As far as what I read now, it seems that it is defined over infinite-dimensional Banach space..

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much(anything) about Fréchet Derivatives. Here is something though: Every Banach space has what is called a Hamel Basis, and every element can be written as a linear combination of finitely many terms in this basis. So the derivative operator would have only a finite number of nonzero "rows". So you certainly couldn't "integrate" a linear operator which has infinite nonzero rows. The downside is that it is pretty much impossible to represent a given linear operator with respect to this basis, since its existence follows from the Axiom of Choice :(.